# Grails database migration changelog "rebase"

Tags: database, grails, grails-plugin, database-migration

Is there an easy way to do a "git rebase"-like operation for Grails Database Migration plugin changelog scripts?

I have already several changelog scripts on top of the initial changelog from an old domain model. Now I'm deploying the application to a new environment and there's no need to migrate the database contents.

I could delete the scripts and generate a fresh initial script from the current domain model but then I'd have to install Grails to the old environment and execute `dbm-clear-checksums` there, right?

Is there an easier way to tell dbm that I don't want to create an old domain and patch it to current level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the [dbm-changelog-sync](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-changelog-sync.html) script - it marks everything as having been run.